# ZBuffer issues with homebrew rendering engine

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 3d, rendering

I'm having trouble with the zbuffer in my rendering engine. I wrote it from scratch, without much prior knowledge on 3D graphics. Transformations work perfectly, as tested without the zbuffer. However, it doesn't draw in the proper order when the buffer is enabled.

Here's how it's implemented.

The Scene class has a render method, which is called by a JFrame whenever it needs to be updated. Render clears the zbuffer, then passes the command to the scene's shapes. Renderable is an interface. Code is as follows:

```
public void render(Graphics2D g2, int pitch, int yaw, int roll) 
{
    for(double[] d : buffer)
        Arrays.fill(d, Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    for(Renderable shape : shapes)
        shape.render(image, pitch, yaw, roll, buffer);
    g2.drawImage(image, null, null);
    for(int x = 0; x < 512; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < 512; y++)
            image.setRGB(x, y, 0); //Clear buffered image
}

private Renderable[] shapes;
private double[][] buffer = new double[512][512];
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Here's the code for the Render method in Triangle3D (implements Renderable).

```
public void render(BufferedImage image, int pitch, int yaw, int roll, double[][] buffer, boolean showBorders)
{
    Triangle3D rotated = (Triangle3D) getRotated(pitch, yaw, roll);
    rotated.translate(256, 256, 0);
    Polygon path = new Polygon();
    path.addPoint(rotated.getFirst().getFirst().intValue(), rotated.getFirst().getSecond().intValue());
    path.addPoint(rotated.getSecond().getFirst().intValue(), rotated.getSecond().getSecond().intValue());
    path.addPoint(rotated.getThird().getFirst().intValue(), rotated.getThird().getSecond().intValue());

    Rectangle bounds = path.getBounds();
    int minY = Math.max(Math.min(bounds.y, 511), 0);
    int maxY = Math.max(Math.min(bounds.y + bounds.height, 511), 0);
    int minX = Math.max(Math.min(bounds.x, 511), 0);
    int maxX = Math.max(Math.min(bounds.x + bounds.width, 511), 0);

    for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++) 
        for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
            if(path.contains(x, y) && buffer[x][y] < getZ(x, y))
            {
                image.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
                buffer[x][y] = getZ(x, y);
            }
}

public double getZ(int x, int y)
{
    double a = getFirst().getFirst();
    double b = getFirst().getSecond();
    double c = getFirst().getThird();

    double d = getSecond().getFirst();
    double e = getSecond().getSecond();
    double f = getSecond().getThird();

    double g = getThird().getFirst();
    double h = getThird().getSecond();
    double w = getThird().getThird();

    double v1a = d - a;
    double v1b = e - b;
    double v1c = f - c;
    double v2a = g - a;
    double v2b = h - b;
    double v2c = w - c;

    double i = v1b * v2c - v1c * v2b;
    double j = v1c * v2a - v1a * v2c;
    double k = v1a * v2b - v1b * v2a;

    double o = (a * i) + (b * j) + (c * k);

    return ((o - (x * i) - (y * j)) / k);
}
```

I've noticed that the Triangle3D rendered last (the last item in Scene's shapes[]) is never visible, even when it should be drawn in front.

Any idea why it isn't working?

Full code:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bw-Cg4sUAOWvS3BTazgyeTRRUjg&usp=sharing

Comment: Why does `Triangle3D` draw to a new image, which it colors where necessary and then drawn onto `g2`, as opposed to just receiving an image which it colors where necessary - and the render loop then draws onto the `g2`? It seems unnecessary to keep allocating images and painting, when you could just allocate 1 image and paint once.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the `z` calculation works. It appears to be written in terms of a rotation (I am guessing that the `getFirst()`, `getSecond()` etc are the elements of the 3x3 rotation matrix) - where is the translation considered? (I don't know if you have ever come across the fact that OpenGL uses a 4x4 matrix which allows the rotation and translation to be passed around together - called *homogeneous notation*, since the two are not considered different)

Comment: Changing the parameter from g2 to a buffered image should help with efficiency. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Triangle3D and Point3D extend a Triplet class, which just holds 3 datum and allows access and mutation. I found it easier to do that, than write a getX(), getY(), getZ(), etc, for each class. That's where the getFirst-Third come from.

The Z calculation comes from the plane equation: ax + by + cz = d. Simple 3D geometry. Translation isn't implemented yet. I plan to translate over the coordinate points, instead of a 4x4 skew.

Comment: If you run the JAR in the full-code link, you'll see that rotation works. My concern is about the z buffer not working.

Comment: I can confirm that getZ() works, and that rotation works. Mathematically and empirically sound.

Comment: @AndyTurner updated Full Code link, now passes a BufferedImage as an argument to Render. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getZ() returns the Z value of the un-rotated triangle. Make it rotated.getZ() instead